# How can i make the preview image bigger?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, image-preview, adminform

I am making a module that will pretty much do the same with the catalog->product manager do.
In my module i need to upload an image.Everything is fine so far.The problem is that i can't find a way when i have upload an image and go to edit that product, the image is 22x22 px.

My field is in the form is like that:

```
$fieldset->addField('imagebook', 'image', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('books')->__('Image'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'imagebook',

       ));
```

So my question is from the image below.How can i make that image bigger?When i edit the css that magento uses it change all the preview images for all the site.

[image: Preview image]

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: doesnt your body-element have a specific class regarding your module you can tie the changes to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add html content after your element, use following:

```
$field = $fieldset->addField('imagebook', 'image', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('books')->__('Image'),
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'imagebook',
));

$imageUrl = Mage::registry('model')->getImageUrl();

$field->setAfterElementHtml(
    "<img src='$imageUrl' class='some_class'/> "
);
```

Here `$imageUrl` is link to uploaded image, I get it from my model, but yours may be differ, you can get it using own logic. And also add some css rules for `some_class`.

Answer (score 2):

The image that you have stated is added via the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Image` class which in turn uses the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image`

If you look into the function `getElementHtml` on `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image` you will see the hard coded height and width.

```
/**
 * Return element html code
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getElementHtml()
{
    $html = '';

    if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
        $url = $this->_getUrl();

        if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $url;
        }

        $html = '<a href="' . $url . '"'
            . ' onclick="imagePreview(\'' . $this->getHtmlId() . '_image\'); return false;">'
            . '<img src="' . $url . '" id="' . $this->getHtmlId() . '_image" title="' . $this->getValue() . '"'
            . ' alt="' . $this->getValue() . '" height="22" width="22" class="small-image-preview v-middle" />'
            . '</a> ';
    }
    $this->setClass('input-file');
    $html .= parent::getElementHtml();
    $html .= $this->_getDeleteCheckbox();

    return $html;
}
```

I would suggest that you could rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Image` class and create a `getElementHtml` function that will set the width and height you want.

Alternatively you could use the event `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_element_types` and create a custom type handler. You would then need to update the field type when adding from `image` to something like `new_image`.

```
$response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
$types = $response->getTypes();
$types['new_image'] = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('new_image/element_image');
$response->setTypes($types);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted the answer of @mageUz and it works but I also found that solution which is faster and easier I think.
If you add a css file inside skin/adminhtml/default/default/yourfile.css with that it makes the trick:

```
#imagebook_image {
display: block;
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 200px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

imagebook_image is made by your column name and type.I haven't found anything to be broken.